# How do I reset a DeathCount in java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, version-differences

Full command, please.
I've tried a lot, but nothing worked.
Also, I've forgotten the command completely.
Please help me as fast as possible. I'm opening a server on 21-1-2022 but I can't reset the counter.

Comment: "I've tried a lot" - please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Just do `/scoreboard players reset @a (ScoreboardName)`
If you want to make the deathcounter again just do `/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount {displayname}` The display name is optional.
For Showing the objective in the right corner type: `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar (ScoreboardName)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I suggest * instead of @a, as @a only targets those players that are currently online. * targets every score on the objective.